# Output redirection, pipe and ``

Tags: bash, pipe, io-redirection

I am trying to pass result of `which env` to `nano` by this command `nano < which env`, but it seems, that I didn't understand the whole concept.

When I execute this I assume that: `which env` STDOUT will go to the `nano` STDIN. So this will equal to `nano /some/path`. But, apparently, I am wrong.

Also I tried `which env | nano` with same purpose, but output was:

> Received SIGHUP or SIGTERM

Can somebody clarify this?

Comment: `which env | nano -`, where `-` means stdin.

Comment: @MetNP same result

Comment: then your nano version is older (must be >=2.2 for stdin feature, you can check with nano -V ). then workarround would be: `nano <(which env)`

Comment: I'm assuming that `env` in your system is something editable by nano (it's a 64-bit Mach executable on mine, so I don't really want to risk corrupting it), so I substituted the `cd` command and `nano $(which cd)` does what you are expecting, at least on OSX.

Comment: @ThomasN @MetNP Yes, also I can `nano `which env``, but also I hoped for a little bit more detailed answer with explanation how it works and why my solution does not.

Answer (score 1):

`nano`, like most text editors, expects a file name to edit as its command-line argument, not as standard input.

```
$ which env | nano    # pass as standard input, does not work
$ nano "$(which env)" # pass as command-line argument, works
```

So it's not working because that's not how nano expects to be used.

With some editors (apparently not your version of nano), you can use:

```
$ which env | some-other-editor -  # note hyphen as file name
```

to *edit* standard input as text (you'd be editing a document with the string "/usr/bin/env", not the program /usr/bin/env itself).

Also, if you want to change delimited names on standard input into arguments, `xargs` will do that for you.

PS: `which` doesn't always do what you want, consider `command -v` instead. For details, see 
*[Why not use "which"? What to use then?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then)*